# Why am I receiving an error for ROCR while predicting binary in R?

Tags: r, roc

I have created a binary variable `carslogic$Mpg01` which lets me know if the MPG of cars in my dataset is above median(1) or below the median(0).

I have completed creating a logistic regression, confusion matrix, and also found the odds ratio, however, after loading the ROCR library and running the below code I am receiving these errors which I am not familiar with:

```
> ROCRpred <- prediction(1-predict, carslogic$Mpg01)
Error in 1 - predict : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> ROCRperf <- performance(ROCRpred, 'tpr','fpr')
Error in performance(ROCRpred, "tpr", "fpr") : 
  object 'ROCRpred' not found
```

I also tried to create a new variable in the dataset called Mpg02 where I converted binary to Yes/No eg: 0 to No and 1 to Yes. However, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post more code leading up to this? Hard to answer without knowing your dataset and how you generated the predict object

Answer (score 0):

I guess your predict vector should be something like  predic(fitted.model) where fitted.model is the results of your model.